# CoreData making entities for two independent list

Tags: core-data

How can you manage two exclusive lists with CoreData? 
It is like messaging app.

i.e)
I want to be able to add/remove attributes to one entity while being able to remove/add attributes to another entity.

ContactEntity with attributes :
John Doe
Jane Doe
Jonnie Doe

BlockEntity with attributes :
Noname Doe

Would two entities without relationship do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you just trying to find out if it's possible to have more than one entity type without having a relationship between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking about this the wrong way. You cannot persist contacts via attributes.

You should simply have one entity (for the described purpose), called `User`. This entity could have two to-many relationships (`contacts` and `blockedUsers`) to the same `User` entity.

```
User
  - first 
  - last 
  - email
  <--->> contacts (User)
  <--->> blockedUsers (User)
```

Accessing all contacts is now as simple as `user.contacts`.
Accessing all blocked users is now as simple as `user.blockedUsers`.

Comment: I solve it now, by adding BOOL type attribute 'blocked'.  I could just fetch with predicate.  So one entity hold all users with 'blocked' BOOL.  Your suggestion might be useful for chat like app.  Thanks.

Comment: That is only half the solution. What about A blocks B, but C likes B. B has the blocked boolean, so C sees B as blocked?? You should select my answer as the correct one (tick the check mark) regardless of what compromise you settle on.